# Does Rust have anything like scanf?

Tags: string, parsing, rust

I need to parse a file with on each line

```
<string><space><int><space><float>
```

e.g.

```
abce 2 2.5
```

In C I would do:

```
scanf("%s%d%f", &s, &i, &f);
```

How can I do this easily and idiomatically in Rust?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The standard library doesn't provide this functionality. You could write your own with a macro.

```
macro_rules! scan {
    ( $string:expr, $sep:expr, $( $x:ty ),+ ) => {{
        let mut iter = $string.split($sep);
        ($(iter.next().and_then(|word| word.parse::<$x>().ok()),)*)
    }}
}

fn main() {
    let output = scan!("2 false fox", char::is_whitespace, u8, bool, String);
    println!("{:?}", output); // (Some(2), Some(false), Some("fox"))
}
```

The second input argument to the macro can be a &str, char, or the appropriate closure / function. The specified types must implement the FromStr trait.

Note that I put this together quickly so it hasn't been tested thoroughly.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`text_io`](https://crates.io/crates/text_io) crate for scanf-like input that mimicks the `print!` macro in syntax

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;

fn main() {
    // note that the whitespace between the {} is relevant
    // placing any characters there will ignore them but require
    // the input to have them
    let (s, i, j): (String, i32, f32);
    scan!("{} {} {}\n", s, i, j);
}
```

You can also split it into 3 commands each:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate text_io;

fn main() {
    let a: String = read!("{} ");
    let b: i32 = read!("{} ");
    let c: f32 = read!("{}\n");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The [scan_fmt](https://crates.io/crates/scan_fmt/) crate offers another alternative. It supports simple patterns, returns its output in options and has a syntax that I find nicer to [text_io](https://crates.io/crates/text_io) :

```
#[macro_use] extern crate scan_fmt;

fn main() {
    let (s, i, j) = scan_fmt!("abce 2 2.5", "{} {d} {f}\n", String, i32, f32);
    println!("{} {} {}", s.unwrap(), i.unwrap(), j.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: Not my favorite because no error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to replicate the exact way that `scanf` parses things for some reason, I think the best answer in the majority of cases (and in the majority of languages) is "just use `regex`." Here's a Rust example:

```
use regex::Regex;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn parse_line(s: &str) -> Option<(String, i32, f32)> {
    let r = Regex::new(r"(\w+) (-?\d+) (-?[0-9]*.?[0-9]*)").unwrap();
    let caps = r.captures(s)?;
    let a = caps.get(1)?.as_str().to_string();
    let b = caps.get(2)?.as_str().parse().ok()?;
    let c = caps.get(3)?.as_str().parse().ok()?;
    Some((a, b, c))
}

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let stdin = stdin.lock();
    for line in stdin.lines() {
        println!("{:?}", parse_line(&line.unwrap()));
    }
}
```

Using regex does raise some immediate questions, especially around float parsing. Do you want to support negative numbers? Is a decimal point with no digits a valid float? Is exponential notation allowed? In a quick-and-dirty data parser, you'll probably just support whatever your data is doing. In a real application, this parser decision might become an important API detail of your app, so it could pay to be conservative at first.

Comment: One note about this solution is that the regular expression here is compiled on each line iteration. Instead you probably want to pass the compiled regular expression into the function by reference, or use something like the lazy_static! macro to do this only once on the first function call. I personally prefer the former style, and will often wrap my regex's in a struct with a new() that compiles them and eats any compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm liking https://docs.rs/scanf/latest/scanf/ because it's easier (less memorization/more readable) than the regex example and provides functionality the other answers don't, such as handling input strings like `"abce:2,3.5"` (the others can only do whitespace separators; the top example (which didn't compile for me) could theoretically do other separators but not with the character-by-character flexibility that scanf gives you.)

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, depending on what kind of work you're doing, learning regular expressions to the point where they are second nature is an extremely useful skill worth acquiring.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/
It's not so much that I don't like regular expressions - it's that I think that particular example of regex is less readable than scanf. *Maybe* that's because I'm more familiar with scanf, but I believe it's actually because it looks more like a string of line noise to me than an attempt to communicate. It's certainly not "so beautiful it makes my eyes water." But I've qualified my entry.